# sorting text data (like numbers) so the numerical value is followed

Tags: sql, db2, alphanumeric

In databases if I have a text field with numbers as part of the data, and I try to sort, the numbers don't come back sequentially, but rather 'pseudo' alphabetically.

I 'expect' this behavior and am comfortable with it. However a user has requested if possible to have things sorted numerically AND alphabetically.

EXAMPLE DATA (sorted):

```
100
1001
1110
1010101E
2
200
22ER
Abd
Bre
```

Where the customer - wants "2" to sort BEFORE "100", and "200" to sort before "1001"
where this gets sticky is where the number/letter combos occur. This issues is due to a fact that the items being named can be named anything ("Box-one", "Box 1", "Box1", "1Box" "1" etc...) like ordering by "firstname" but many people name their kid a digit - sorting is a nightmare.

I've toyed with the idea of doing a UNION of all the "numerical only" fields, cast to number and sorted, then union'd with the alpha-nums... So at least the numbers were "as expected" - but the overhead seems outrageous.

Following the user's request I'd expect that "2erd" should sort before "100" and "22Asd" would sort before "22asd"

Any suggestions or solutions? This must come up.
We're using DB2 v9.5

leading zeros is also an "issue" as "0000123" sorts before "122"

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: and on what platform? z/OS, I presume?

Comment: linux (suse & slackware)

Comment: Then there's no such thing as DB2 v9: is it 9.1, 9.5, or 9.7?

Comment: thx for being so precise mustaccio, I didn't know the dot number, as I'm not the guy who manages the db... however I'd be surprised if the sort functionality is changed along ANY version in the 9 series... so I question if the smack down was needed.

9.5 is our current version -

Comment: The sort functionality, as you put it, does not change, however, functions that are available for data type transformation do.

Comment: fair enough, but without offering a solution, it becomes a debate on a different topic. Do you know of a data transformation in 9.7 that will work? or 9.5? or 9.1? - or ANY system? I was able to try Gordon Linoff's suggestion below - with no luck. result set still is "out of numeric order" - I also tried another suggestion that has been removed... "order by len(data), data" which seemed to work except for leading zeros as "0077" sorted AFTER "100" and I don't have data like "a" but I suspect it would sort before "22" - and this might be where my Union idea can combine with Gordon's suggestion

Comment: Check out my answer below. I needed this information for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a 9.5 instance handy but this should work as it uses only the functionality available in DB2 9.5:

```
  db2 => with input (f) as ( 
    values ('100'), ('1001'), ('1110'), ('1010101E'),
   ('2'), ('200'), ('22ER'), ('Abd'), ('Bre')
  )
  select * from input
  order by case 
    when 
      length(trim(translate(f,'','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))) = 0 
        then 9999999999999 -- alpha only; make sure it sorts after all numbers
    else 
      integer(trim(translate(f,'','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))) -- convert to integer 
  end, -- this column is numeric
  case
    when 
      length(trim(translate(f,'','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))) = 0 
        then f -- alpha only
    else '' -- nothing; sorts before other strings 
  end
  ; 

  F       
  --------
  2       
  22ER    
  100     
  200     
  1001    
  1110    
  1010101E
  Abd     
  Bre     

    9 record(s) selected.
```

The TRANSLATE function is used to remove non-numeric characters from the column values, allowing you to sort the remaining data numerically.

Comment: this looks promising but I'm getting SQL Error [22018]: Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "INTEGER".. SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, DRIVER=3.59.81
  Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "INTEGER".. SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, DRIVER=3.59.81

Comment: The issue occurs where there is a non alphanumeric in the string such as '10%01' ... most likely an underscore or dash in our data set

Comment: Well then your sample data were incomplete. The solution quality is only as good as the question. Add all possible non-numeric characters to the translate list. You may also consider the possibility of non-integer numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, you can do:

```
order by field+0, field
```

MySQL automatically does a conversion of the left-most characters in a string for an arithmetic operation.

In other databases, this seems to be more difficult.  In some, you can use REGEXP to replace a pattern (such as removing all characters after the first non-digit).  Or, you might have to loop through the characters themselves, with something like:

```
order by (case when left(field, 5) not like '[^0-9]' then cast(left(field, 5) as int)
               when left(field, 4) not like '[^0-9]' then cast(left(field, 4) as int)
               when left(field, 3) not like '[^0-9]' then cast(left(field, 3) as int)
               when left(field, 2) not like '[^0-9]' then cast(left(field, 2) as int)
               when left(field, 1) not like '[^0-9]' then cast(left(field, 1) as int)
           end), field
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to trim and right justify your strings. Let's say your column is 20 characters wide. You could use something like

```
right(repeat(' ',20)||trim(yourdata),20)
```

Granted, this doesn't work so well if the string starts with non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like (assuming sortfield is less than 11 chars, if it is longer
you will need to increase the number of zeros and truncation point or put in a test):

**Order by right(concat("0000000000", sortField), 10)**